# Javascript Push/Shift same element multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have the following code:

```
var foo = 'foo'
var bar = 'bar'
var arr = [1,2,3]
```

I want to add to `foo` several times at the beginning of the array and `bar` at the end of the array. The number of times each element added should be dynamic and the resulting array should be something like:

`['foo','foo',1,2,3,'bar',bar','bar']`

Is there a better method than using a loop for each element?I could use lodash if needed.

Comment: Simple answer, no.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If *better* means *shorter*, yes there's a way:

```
 var foo = 'foo';
 var bar = 'bar' 
 var arr = [1,2,3]

 var result = [
   ...Array(2).fill(foo),
   ...arr,
   ...Array(3).fill(bar)
];
```

Comment: I like this solution (+1) but FYI - doesnt support IE < 12 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 2):

Or something like this.

```js
var foo = Array.from({length:2}, v => 'foo');
var bar = Array.from({length:3}, v => 'bar');
var arr = [1,2,3]

arr.push(...bar);
arr.unshift(...foo);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `forloop` method. [`Array#unshift()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_unshift.asp) added the value on starting of array.`push` add with end of the array

```js
var foo = 'foo'
var bar = 'bar'
var arr = [1,2,3]

for(var i=0; i<(Math.random() * 5); i++){
arr.unshift(foo)
}
for(var i=0; i<(Math.random() * 5); i++){
arr.push(bar)
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like

```js
function pushToBeginning(arr, str, count){
    while(count--){
        arr.unshift(str);
    }
}

function pushToEnd(arr, str, count){
    while(count--){
        arr.push(str);
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3];

pushToBeginning(arr, 'Foo', 3);
pushToEnd(arr, 'Bar', 2);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the answers here use spread syntax or for loops to push. But its recommended to use `Array.concat()` for [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866316/6908282) & to [avoid stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719431/6908282):

```js
var foo = 'foo';
var bar = 'bar'
var arr = [1, 2, 3]

var result = arr.concat(Array(2).fill(foo), Array(3).fill(bar));
console.log(result)
```

> Note that - according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832006/6908282) `Array.fill` is only recommended for primitive data types.
>
> for non-primitives, you need to use `Array.from` because then all elements in the array will reference the same object in memory, so mutations to one item in the array will affect every item in the array